# angular pwa in offline mode

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, offline

Angular 10, SSR, PWA, firebase hosting

I created a PWA application.

with one connection I install it on my system and everything works.
I cut the internet, I can continue browsing.
on the other hand, when I do an F5 refresh, I get an HTTP ERROR 504 page

is there a solution?

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 10 - SSR - PWA

with **lighthouse**:

*PROTOCOL_TIMEOUT
Channel: DevTools
Initial URL: https://blog-iner-code.web.app/home
Chrome Version: 86.0.4240.198
Stack Trace: LHError: PROTOCOL_TIMEOUT
at eval (devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@d8a506935fc2273cfbac5e5b629d74917d9119c7/lighthouse_worker/lighthouse_worker_module.js:1589:229)*

in application, "service worker" is detected